# Showing saved images in directory to a Collection View

Tags: ios, directory, save, uicollectionview, photo

Usually when you have the images in the project file you use the code

```
arraycollectionimages = [[NSArray alloc]]initwithobjects
```

however I want to show the images that are saved in the directories.  I have created multiple directories so I just want to recall image for one of them.  To make this work I want to use this code however I cannot do this?  I just stuck it it in as follows but did not work well.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *arrayCollectionImages = [[NSArray alloc ]init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"Genre1";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [arrayCollectionImages addObject:image];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your directory search is probably taking long. Try this...

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            dispatch_queue_t searchQ = dispatch_queue_create("com.awesome", 0);
            dispatch_async(searchQ, ^{
            NSArray *arrayCollectionImages = [[NSArray alloc ]init];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *location=@"Genre1";
            NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
            NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
            for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
                NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
                if(data)
                {   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    });
                    [arrayCollectionImages addObject:image];
                }
            }
    });

}
```

The code basically spawns off another thread on the search and puts the image when its ready.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering I am getting an error in images at the `[arrayCollectionImages addObject:image];` Can you explain me about this last piece of code. I also have an warning at arrayCollectionImages saying local declaration of arrayColectionImages hide instance variable.

Comment: For `addObject` you need an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Yeah, you need to change arraycollectionimages = [[NSArray alloc]]initwithobjects TO .... arraycollectionimages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]]initwithobjects